# C Program to search for numbers NOT in the Fibonacci Sequence

Tags: c, fibonacci

I want help in writing a **simple** program in **C Programming Language** that helps the user search for integers **NOT** in the Fibonacci sequence for a given range of integers.
I have the program that displays the Fibonacci numbers in a given sequence for reference.

```
int main()
{
int i;
/* Declare and initialise an int array with the first 2 fibonacci numbers 1 and 1 */
/* The size of the array should be NUM_FIBON. */
int *fibonacci;
int sizeOfArray;
/* Display the purpose of the program */
printf("\nThis program displays the fibonacci numbers\n\n");
printf("Enter the number of Fibonacci numbers to compute: ");
scanf("%i", &sizeOfArray);
fibonacci = malloc(sizeof(int) * sizeOfArray);
fibonacci[0]=1;
fibonacci[1]=1;

/* Populate the array with other fibonacci numbers, starting with the 3rd number */
/* Each fibonacci number is the sum of the previous two */
for(i=2; i<sizeOfArray; i++)
{
 fibonacci[i] = fibonacci[i-1]+fibonacci[i-2];
}

/* Print message: 
 * Calculation over.
 * Press [Enter] to display the first x fibonacci numbers
 *
 * then wait for the [Enter] key to be pressed.  
 */
printf("Calculation over \nPress ENTER to display the first %i fibonacci numbers\n\n", sizeOfArray);
getch();

/* Print the 12 first fibonacci numbers */
for(i=0; i<sizeOfArray; i++)
{
 if (i % 10 == 0)
 {
  printf("\n");
  printf("%-8i", fibonacci[i]);
 }
 else
 {
  printf("%-8i", fibonacci[i]);
 }
}
free(fibonacci);

/* Pause so the result can be seen when the program starts from windows explorer */ 
getch();

/* Return success code to the operating system */
return 0;
```

}

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/1105.1127 helps perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that code is kind of a red herring. You need a function called is_fibbonacci, 1 parameter an int, returns either TRUE or FALSE. You only need 3 variables in a while loop to calculate next fibbonacci until next is greater or equals to parameter.

Comment: could you help me out with the coding for it?

Comment: with the code I've written, i can generate fibonacci numbers but I need a program that generates numbers that are not in the fibonacci sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: rewrite fibbonacci generator to work itteratively, it now takes 1 parameter steps and returns the fib number. So 0 returns 1,1 returns 2, 2 three etc.
Step 2: copy new fibbonacci generator, rename is_fibbonacci. Rename parameter to test_value.
In a loop while(test_value < new_fib), generate new_fib. When the loop breaks return(new_fib==test_value)

Comment: can you help me out with the actual code?
I'm a complete noob when it comes to this stuff

Comment: What's your email, i'll need to use laptop to compile & test before mailing listing

Comment: saad.zafar.7223@live.com

Comment: Hey, i'd probably redact my email address above. Also please publish the code i emailed to you, others will also be helped.